# Counterexample in axioms of expected utility theory

Tags: economics, utility

This is an exercise problem.

Suppose $X_1=200$ with probability $1/3$, $0$ with probability $2/3$.

$X_2=200$ with probability $p$, $0$ with probability $1-p$.

$X_3=200$ with probability $1-p$, $0$ with probability $p$.

$X_4=200$ with probability $2/3$, $0$ with probability $1/3$.

I am asked to show that the preference $X_1\succ X_2$, $X_4\succ X_3$ cannot be represented through expected utility for any choice of $p\in[0,1]$.

I tried to write it in the form $X_1\sim p_1\sim1/3\delta_{200}+2/3\delta_0$, etc. and was trying to find a contradiction with the independence axiom by $X_1\succ X_2$ implying $X_3\succ X_4$ using the independence axiom. But I don't know how to deal with the general p term. I'm greatly thankful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ denote the utility function.

Then $X_1\succ X_2$ implies $$\frac{1}{3}U(200) + \frac{2}{3}U(0) > pU(200) + (1-p)U(0), \\\ \Big(\frac{1}{3}-p\Big)U(200) > \Big(\frac{1}{3}-p\Big)U(0).$$

But $X_4\succ X_3$ implies $$\frac{2}{3}U(200) + \frac{1}{3}U(0) > (1-p)U(200) + pU(0), \\\ \Big(\frac{1}{3}-p\Big)U(0) > \Big(\frac{1}{3}-p\Big)U(200).$$

Hence, we have a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks so much. By the way, do you assume the U to be linear?

Comment: No I'm just assuming it is a general rational utility function. I believe it must be non-decreasing if the preference is weakly monotone and strictly increasing if the preference is monotone. If the inequalities were not strict then you would show that $U(200)=U(0)$ which would either be impossible if $U$ is strictly increasing or show that $U$ is a constant, which i believe is also not allowed.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!